# Putting turtles into groups: modified partners example?

Tags: netlogo

I've been trying to write a model in NetLogo where I start with a certain number of turtles with random starting co-ordinates. When I hit go, I want the turtles to go into groups of a certain size and then continue to move. I know there is an example model for grouping ('grouping turtles example'), but it tells turtles to go to a certain patch rather than to group together, so if they move they are no longer grouped.

I have been modifying the 'partner example' model from the models library. Here, turtles are told to find another turtle that doesn't have a partner yet, to set that turtle as its partner, and then to tell that new parter to set it as a partner too. This works fine and I can tell partners to flock, keeping them together as a group as they continue to move. But I can't figure out how I could get something like this to work with more than a pair of turtles.

I thought I could make an agentset of 'partners' which would include all the partners that an individual turtle has. I've also thought about using undirected links between turtles and using an agentset of 'network' to include all turtles connected to an individual turtle.

I can't get either of these ideas to work. When using links, I can set the preferred number of links a turtle can have, but not total number of turtles in the entire group (including link-neighbors of link-neighbors), and turtles in a group don't share the same connections. It never seems to work when I try to make an agentset of partners, because each subsequent parter over-rides the previous one. I also need to make sure that an individual turtle shares the same partners as others in its group. I've been trying to use 'turtle-set' to add a new partner to any previous partners, but I'm having problems. Here is the code I've been using for setting partners:

```
turtles-own
[next-partner ;a partner to be added to partners   
  group-size  ;includes turtle itself and number of partners in group (count)
  partners]   ;agentset of partners

to setup
  clear-all
  create-turtles num-turtles 
  [ setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set next-partner nobody ;turtles haven't got any partners to start with
    set group-size 1 ;just itself
   ]
    reset-ticks
end

to go
  let singles turtles with [preferred-size > group-size] ;those turtles where the group it's in isn't big enough

  ask singles
  [ifelse any? other singles
  [set heading towards min-one-of (other turtles with [preferred-size > group-size]) [distance myself]] ;go towards other turtles who need more members in group
  [lt random 40
    rt random 40]
    fd 1
  ]

  ask turtles
   [set partners turtles with [next-partner = myself] ;partners are those turtles who have you in their partners, but I don't this will work because they won't always be a 'next-partner'
    set group-size 1 + count partners  
    if (preferred-size > group-size) and (any? other turtles in-radius 1 with [preferred-size > group-size])

    [set next-partner one-of other turtles in-radius 1 with [preferred-size > group-size]

     ask next-partner 
      [set next-partner myself  ;ask this new partner to set turtle as its partner too
       set partners (turtle-set partners next-partner)]  ;add the turtle as a partner to the partners agentset
       set partners (turtle-set partners next-partner) ;turtle does this after partner so that the partner doesn't add itself
      ]
    ask turtles with [preferred-size = group-size] ;turtles in the right group size just move around (I can get them to flock later)
  [lt random 40
    rt random 40
    fd 1]
  ] 
   tick
end
```

I hope this isn't too long and unclear. I'd really appreciate any help, I've been working on this for days and can't find anything like this in previous questions.

Thanks!

Damien

Comment: What about **Flocking** model from models library? (Sample Models/Biology/Flocking.nlogo) It should be a good start...

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The flocking model has been helpful, but I can't use it to put turtles into a group of a specific number of turtles if that makes sense. So I want the turtles to first find a certain number of partners and then to flock with just their partners. I've done this with a single partner (a group of 2), but can't add any more partners..

Comment: You want the groups to be a specific size but do they have to find geographically close turtles or can you assign turtles to groups randomly and then have them move towards others in the same group?

Comment: They don't actually need to be next to each other at all, that was just the way I thought I could do it. I've actually worked out that the 'grouping turtles' model assigns a number to turtles and then tells them to go to a location depending on their number. I've used this number assignment code, but told turtles to flock to other turtles with the same number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the wolf pack example in the Railsback and Grimm: Agent-based and Individual-Based Modeling.  Basically each pack has a unique identifier.

In this case a group would have that identifier.  So when flocking occurs those in the flock allow others to join and the group identifier is given to the new member or group that is created.  If they leave the identifier is reset.  You can easily set rules around new relationships [two new turtles meeting and generating a new group number], group growth [numbers of existing in a group and new ones arriving or being rejected], and those leaving group [reset group numbers].  The good thing about this is you can also easily create agent-sets of those with the same group number and so get them all to do the same thing.

Comment: Thanks! I actually just bought that book, but haven't gone through it yet. The 'Grouping Turtles Example' model actually did a similar thing where it gave each turtle a number. I've used that to get what I wanted.